# Getting Json from files and folders

Tags: json

In the music folder on the hosting there was a folder of type

```
Folder № 1
Folder № 2
...
Folder № N
```

Each folder has its own audio

```
Audio № 1
Audio № 2
...
Audio № N
```

How can I get a JSON file from these folders and files as?

```
{
  "music": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "Folder": "Folder № 1",
      "Audio": "Audio № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 1 / Audio № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Folder": "Folder № 1",
      "Audio": "Audio № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 1 / Audio № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "Folder": "Folder № 1",
      "Audio": "Audio № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 1 / Audio № 3.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "Folder": "Folder № 2",
      "Audio": "Audio № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 2 / Audio № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "Folder": "Folder № 2",
      "Audio": "Audio № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 2 / Audio № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "Folder": "Folder № 2",
      "Audio": "Audio № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 2 / Audio № 3.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "Folder": "Folder № 3",
      "Audio": "Audio № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 3 / Audio № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "Folder": "Folder № 3",
      "Audio": "Audio № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 3 / Audio № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "Folder": "Folder № 3",
      "Audio": "Audio № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/ Folder № 3 / Audio № 3.mp3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to finally get the finished file and use it in the Android application. I hope for your help. Thank.

I did not find ready solutions on the Internet.

Comment: So how exactly are you accessing the host path? Which framework or language you are using?

Comment: I have a website on the hosting. On the site folder music. I can get access to files by accessing via FTP or hosting a control panel.